# Largest triangle that contains a point

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, search

Given the location of $n$ points on a 2D plane ($P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n$); and the location of a special point $X$.

Find three points $P_i,P_j,P_k$ ($i \neq j \neq k$) such that point $X$ is inside the triangle $P_iP_jP_k$, and the minimum distance between point $X$ and the three sides of the triangle is the largest.

In other words, let $D_{xij}$ be closest distance between point $X$ and line $P_iP_j$, similarly for $D_{xjk}$ and $D_{xki}$. Find $i, j, k$ that maximizes $\min (D_{xij},D_{xjk},D_{xki})$.

The Naive solution runs in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$. **Goal: an algorithm that is better than $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.**

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Suppose $X$ is in the middle of an equilateral triangle $ABC$, where one third of the $P$'s are near $A$, one third near $B$, and one third near $C$.  Then I think you have to check all $(n/3)^3$ possibilities of one $P_i$ near each of $A,B,C$ to find the optimal enclosing triangle. So I doubt you can do better than $O(n^3)$.